# Possible to migrate 16.04 LTS laptop to full disk (luks) encryption?

Tags: encryption, luks

So I have a laptop and I want to see how hard it is to migrate to full disk encryption. I've done it from a clean install once before and even wrote a HOWTO which I unfortunately no longer have access to ( corporate Wiki ). My expectation is that doing it from a clean install was probably very automated and so a migration might be much harder. I've been searching for guides but they all seem to be marked with some variant of "Duplicate", "Needs Updating",  "Candidate for Deletion", etc. such that it is very hard now to tell which is the most appropriate guide.

Comment: migrate how ? Probably much easier to back up data and do a fresh install

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that.  So afraid that I'm already making backups.

Comment: If you encrypt only your home, you don't need to reinstall every thing.Either way, you will need backup because you can't encrypt in place.

Comment: @solsTiCe Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done such migration once or twice but you have to be able to use google to solve issues that arrise. This is not a full answer, just rough steps of what you need to do. These steps have to be done from Live CD and involve operations with LUKS and LVM, so you might as well get a Live CD containing latest version of KDE Partition Manager 3.0 and use it for LUKS and LVM operations.

If you have enough free space (more than 50%) you can just

- Resize your current partition.
- Create a new LVM2 Physical Volume (PV) encrypted with LUKS.
- Create a new Volume Group containing LVM PV.
- Create new LVM logical volume for your rootfs (and probably swap and all other partitions you might have...). I myself use btrfs with subvolumes, so I only had btrfs and swap.
- Move your data to encrypted partitions
- Delete unencrypted partitions
- Deactivate LVM and deactivate your LUKS container
- Move LUKS container to the beginning of the disk (space freed by deletion of unencrypted data)
- Open your LUKS container again.
- Grow your LUKS container so that it fills entire disk.
- Grow LVM LV containing your root file system.

Then you will have to update entries in /etc/fstab, create /etc/crypttab, chroot into your encrypted rootfs, update your initramfs and grub configuration.

This still leaves /boot unencrypted. You can encrypt /boot too but this adds a few extra steps, so first make sure everything above works. In order to encrypt boot, you have to move contents of /boot partition info your rootfs/boot/. Then in /etc/default/grub you need to add `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` and remove old unencrypted /boot. Then again you will have to update entries in /etc/fstab, create /etc/crypttab, chroot into your encrypted rootfs, update your initramfs and grub configuration. After these steps grub will be asking for passphrase before booting, however it does not pass it to initramfs on boot, so cryptsetup will be asking it again. Therefore you will need to add a luks key file to your luks container and put it in your initramfs. E.g. my /etc/crypttab file contains

```
luks-MYUUID UUID=MYUUID /boot/crypto_keyfile.bin luks
```